# Edits not saving in Case Activity Tab since 4.7.4 upgrade

Tags: civicase, activities

If I edit an activity (eg the date or the status) in the Activities tab of the Manage Case page, I get the confirmation message "[activity name] saved". But the edit is not saved.

This problem only appeared after upgrading to 4.7.4. There are no JS errors, no errors on CiviCRM log, no php errors.

Running Joomla 3.4.8. I can't test on the demo, because it's still on 4.6.

Edit: just tried the Wordpress demo, and the problem is present there as well.

Any suggestions where to look for the problem? Thanks.

Comment: We can see this too.

Comment: Oh dear. I was hoping it was just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have found the solution, but I'm not sure.

At line 418 of civicrm/CRM/Case/Form/Activity.php there is this command:
        **$params = array_merge($params, $oldActivity);**
But this seems to be the wrong way round. I changed it to:
        **$params = array_merge($oldActivity, $params);**

This change appears to fix the problem, but I don't really know what I'm doing, so no guarantees.

Comment: Now submitted as a pull request here:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8024/files

Comment: PR committed as fix in 4.7.5

Answer (score 1):

Verified now that the issue is a general problem with CiviCase in Drupal, Joomla and Wordpress versions. I have raised a bug report [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18290?filter=-2).

Answer (score 0):

I know you aren't seeing errors in your logs, however, I did see errors when I attempted to change the Case Type.  Here's the link:
[With an upgrade to 4.7.3, Civicase has become inoperable](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/with-an-upgrade-to-4-7-3-civicase-has-become-inoperable/10606?noredirect=1#comment10786_10606)

There's a comment, perhaps buried, about removing Roles from Case Types, and then things worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. Since the error only occurs in 4.7.4, and even occurs in a virgin version of CiviCase on the Demo sites (ie without adding any roles to the default case type), I assume that the problem is probably not related to the link you mentioned.